# Spring Hibernate create new tables with out losing the existing tables

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am working on a Spring/Hibernate/Postgres Project. I have couple of tables on which I am performing CRUD operations and the tables have data I dont want to lose. I now want to create a new table with Hibernate entity class, with out losing my existing tables. will this do it for me:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

I want to confirm that I will create the new table with out deleting the existing tables

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to confirm it!

Comment: Well, I created @Entity class and set the auto the update, and I do not see a new table in the postgres DB. DO I have to do anything else for it to create the table?

Comment: did you specified annotated class in hibernate config ?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same question, I did the same but the table is not getting created, what exactly do you mean by "specifying the annotated class in hibernate config" [@invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986387/invariant)

Comment: This should be a comment